# Unsupported SSL protocol version

Tags: git, ssl, curl, homebrew

whenever I try to use the `git clone` command my mac gives me this error

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hammad1015/CN_project
Cloning into 'CN_project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hammad1015/CN_project/': Unsupported SSL protocol version
```

similarly whenever I try to install something using brew same error happens

```
brew install php
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Unsupported SSL protocol version
```

with curl

```
$ curl https://google.com/ --tlsv1.2 --verbose
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 142.250.180.46...
* Connected to google.com (142.250.180.46) port 443 (#0)
* Unsupported SSL protocol version
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unsupported SSL protocol version
```

Comment: What if you say `git clone git@github.com:hammad1015/CN_project.git` instead?

Comment: @matt this one worked, but whats the difference?

Comment: Http vs. ssh. There is no more http-with-password at GitHub, and that may be what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the TLS (formerly called SSL) protocol version you're using is not supported.  Most major websites have dropped support for TLS versions older than 1.2 and only accept 1.2 and possibly 1.3.

Usually this happens because you're using an older version of a cryptographic library that doesn't support TLS 1.2.  That could be because your version of Git is compiled against an obsolete version of OpenSSL or GnuTLS, or because it's compiled against the Apple Common Crypto library but you're using a version of macOS that's no longer supported.

If it is the case that your OS is out of date, then you should update it to the latest version.  It is important to be sure that you have all security updates applied, especially when dealing with cryptography, because new vulnerabilities are commonly discovered.  Failing to run a fully patched system also exposes your system to compromise, which can then result in it being used as a basis to attack others or spread malware.  In addition, almost all websites will be inaccessible if your system really lacks TLS 1.2 support.

If it is the case that your OS is up to date but you just have some ancient version of Homebrew installed and need to update it, you can run `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Homebrew/brew` in your Homebrew repository to switch to SSH, and then use that to perform the fetch.  Note that you will need an SSH key set up with GitHub for that to work.

Note that if you are using a proxy or TLS middlebox, it may be that it instead is misconfigured to use only obsolete versions of TLS, in which case you should move to a different network or try SSH.

Comment: how do i setup my SSH key? and after that how do I switch back to tls from ssh? sorry im new to all this

Comment: You can [follow the directions on GitHub's docs site](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).  To switch back, run the same `git remote set-url` command, except with the HTTPS URL instead of the SSH URL.